# When some clicks my button I want the product image to be insert into a div on a new page?

Tags: javascript

```
function load_Product () {
    var theDomain = window.location.assign("purchase1.html");
    var imageDiv = document.getElementById('productPicInfo');
    var productImage = document.getElementById('bouqImage1');  //This   is a image on a different page with this id name//
    imageDiv.innerHTML = productImage;  
    sumFunction = theDomain + imageDiv.innerHTML;
}
```

Trying to add image into div but when button is pressed it doesn't appear.

Comment: You cannot access DOM elements of other pages. That is, unless they are iFrames or popups created by `window.open` *and* are on the same domain.

Comment: my bad didnt see new page lol

Comment: Your question is very difficult to answer at this time. With this code we have to guess to where the other page is. Please include your HTML code.

Comment: the image with the id bouqImage1 is part of my website site (purchase1.html.)

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, you want an image that is displayed on a different web page to display on your own webpage when the button is pressed. This is doable.

First note that javascript can't access DOM elements on another page. What you can do is send an http request--every image has it's own URL. So your code would be

```
function load_Product () {
    var imageDiv = document.getElementById('productPicInfo');
    imageDiv.innerHTML = '<img src="http://otherwebsite.com/image.png">';  //change src attribute to the image's URL
}
```

Unless the other website is doing something weird this should work, because the http request is made by the browser, not from javascript, so it doesn't violate the cross-domain policy.

Comment: <tr>
    <td width="203"><img src="images/chocoImage1.png" name="bouqImage1" width="190" height="206" class="birthpic1" id="bouqImage1"/>Candy &amp; Bear Mix $60</td>

Comment: <div id="productPicInfo"></div>

<div class="aside">
  <div class="hours"><!-- TemplateBeginEditable name="hours" -->
    <p><strong>North Las Vegas</strong> Coming Soon!!!<br />
      <strong>Monday-Friday:</strong> 9:00 am — 5:00 pm<br />
      <strong>Saturday: </strong>8:00am — 2:00 pm</p>
  <!-- TemplateEndEditable --></div>

Comment: <td><input type="submit" name="buttomBouq1" id="buttomBouq1" value="Purchase" onclick="load_Product ()"; /></td>